# Remove parents p not working

Tags: javascript

the remove button not working, hers is the original version : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x68jx/) , also im trying to add button to add/remove  question , can i duplicate the same code (to: add /remove questions)?  add new input work fine

```
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>  
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
            var addDiv = $('#optionid');
            var i = $('#optionid').size() + 1;

            $('#addoption').on('click', function() {
            $('<p><div class="row">'+
            '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">'+
            '<label for="">Option #' + i +':</label>'+
            '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="option[' + i +'][option]" >'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">'+
            '<label for="">Value #' + i +':</label>'+
            '<input type="number" class="form-control" id="" name="value[' + i +'][value]" >'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">'+
            '<div class="imad">'+
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="removeoption" >Remove button</button>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);
            i++;


            return false;
            });

            $(document).on("click", "#removeoption", function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
            });

            </script>
    <div id="optionid">

              <div class="row">
              <p>
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
              <label for="">Option #1:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="option[1][option]" >  
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
              <label for="">Value #1:</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="" name="value[1][value]" >  
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
              <div class="imad">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id='addoption'>Add Question</button>   
              </div>

              </div>
              </p>
              </div>

              </div>
```

Comment: Please define "not working". What do you expect your code to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: So, the remove button throws poo to neighbors' windows? Again: define "not working".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [`Event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) is needed as dynamic elements are created. Use `classes` as there can not be multiple elements having same `id`

Use `event.preventDault()` as default behavior of `anchor` tag is navigation/redirection and we want to have click handler instead of that.

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
  var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

  $('#addScnt').click(function() {
    $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
  });

  $('#p_scents').on('click', '.remScnt', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (i > 2) {
      $(this).parents('p').remove();
      i--;
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
}
h2 {
  padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
h2 a {
  color: #224f99;
}
a {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #802727;
}
p {
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}
input {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -web-kit-border-radius: 4px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
  <p>
    <label for="p_scnts">
      <input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />
    </label>
  </p>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/x68jx/10/)